# How to resolve Youtube Data API errors

Tags: youtube-api

Currently our Youtube data API v3 is enabled.

[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]
However, we found there was some error while we calling this API.

[image: Image 3]

The screen shows as the following:

```
Google_Service_Exception : {
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
                "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 10xxxxxxxxx29 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=10xxxxxxxxx29 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.", 
                "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=10xxxxxxxxx29"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 10xxxxxxxxx29 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=10xxxxxxxxx29 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
    }
}
```

We try to create a new O Auth 2.0 ID, but the issue was still got same error.
Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I would double check that the client id you are using is actual from the project you have enabled. The error message states it hasnt been enabled.   Out of quota is a different error message so i dont think its that.

Comment: Hi @DalmTo , thanks we'll also check the client id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google allows for 50000 request per month/per user.So seem your website has high traffic.You can get another API key from your other gmail then put into API settings.Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @TechGuy, that could be possible root cause, due to we just requested to raise our quota by filling form to Google, currently is awaiting for approval.